# Starting a .EXE in multiple windows sessions

Tags: windows

I have a need for starting an .exe program in multiple windows sessions (15) on the same server, whenever the server reboots.

I had a code that used to do that at start-up, but we lost that.

The exe file collects data from a bunch of servers. It needs to be run in multiple windows sessions--I think this way the process works in parallel.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: For the record, the only reason it might be necessary to run the program in multiple sessions is that it was badly designed in the first place.  Presumably you're not correcting the problem in the short term because you can't (for whatever reason) but I do hope you have better long-term plans.

Comment: (I should think the main problem isn't starting the program, but creating the sessions.  There's no automated way to do that as far as I know.)

Comment: Thank you Harry. You are right. The program was designed a long time ago, in a legacy technology. As you pointed out correctly, we do not know, how to start multiple sessions.

Comment: Do they *have* to be in different sessions on the same server?  Could you run them in 15 virtual machines on the same physical server instead?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* they need to be in separate sessions, and not just, e.g., on separate desktops, or using separate accounts?

Comment: Thank you Harry. I don't think they need to run on the same machine. The system was developed long back. 2 servers run 15 sessions each. That would mean 60 boxes, if we plan to run one session on each machine. Thank you for the suggestion. Good to know, different views. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

[`PsExec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) is a tool primarily used for running code on other servers, but can be pointed at the local machine too. The `-i` option can specify a session:

> Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified
>   session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.

Comment: I have used PSExec for some requirements. I'll give it a try and post my findings. Thank you Alex.